How to set Referrer-Policy in Spring Boot?
I want to set HTTP headers in Spring Boot. Specifically, I need to set Referrer-Policy to same-origin.
Therefore, I created the following class:
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.headers(headers -> headers.frameOptions(frameOptions -> frameOptions.sameOrigin()));
        return http.build();
    }
} //  SecurityConfiguration

But when I look with wireshark at the preflight response (Spring app -> browser), I can see that the Referrer-Policy is set to no-referrer.
Any idea?

Why do you want to add Referrer-Policy to a preflight response? That should not be neccessary.

First springboot sends a preflight by default as far as i understand, but set to "no-referrer". Then I receive the following message : Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://zbook.home:8180/realms/Clearances/protocol/openid-connect/token. (Reason: header ‘access-control-allow-headers’ is not allowed according to header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight response).

But that's is a CORS problem, not a problem with any header. So show your CORS configuration.
